# Invoke default error handler in angular 4

Tags: angular

I've defined a customer error handler in my Angular4 application

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error) {  
      switch (error.type) {
        case 'custom': doTheThing(); defaultErrorHandling(); //?
        default: defaultErrorHandling(); // ?
      }
   }
}
```

How can I pass the reins to the default error handling routine when needed?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    handleError(error) {  
      switch (error.type) {
        case 'custom': doTheThing(); return super.handleError(error); //?
        default: return super.handleError(error); // ?
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just console error it:

```
console.error(error)
```